# How to decompose covariance matrice, multiplied by constant, to sample from multivariate normal?

Tags: covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution, matrix-decomposition

I need to sample from multivariate normal distribution with mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma_1$.

For that I want to use the decomposition of $\Sigma_1$ into $UΛ{U}^T$ and samle as $\mu + Lz$ with $L=U\sqrtΛ$ and $z$ being vector of independent standard normal variates.

However, I do not know decomposition of matrix $\Sigma_1$, but do know decomposition of matrix $Σ_0$ such that $Σ_1=const*Σ_0$.

Is there any easy way of calculating decomposition of matrix $Σ_1$ knowing decomposition of matrix $Σ_0$ or is there none?

Comment: 1) It's not clear to me why you can't compute the eigendecomposition of $\Sigma_1$. Do you not know $\Sigma_1$? 2) What decomposition do you know for $\Sigma_0$--is this an eigendecompsition? 3) Do you know the value of the constant that relates $\Sigma_0$ to $\Sigma_1$?

Comment: @user20160 Yes, this is a spectral/eigendecomposition of $\Sigma_0$. I know decomposition of $\Sigma_0$ because I initially construct it from those terms, so they are readily available. Then, I need to compute several decompositions of  different $\Sigma_1$ with different constants (yes, they are known). As $\Sigma_0$ is very large, it would be really convenient for me if there is a way not to compute decomposition of every $\Sigma_1$, but reuse information about $\Sigma_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\Sigma_1=const*\Sigma_0$, then $\Sigma_1$ could be decomposed as $U{\Lambda_1}U^T$ with ${\Lambda_1}=const*{\Lambda_0}$.
So, I could sample as $\mu+{L_1}z$ with $L_1=U\sqrt{const*\Lambda_0}$.

I have verified this working  for my case through computations in `scipy`, however I cannot prove it analytically.

Comment: What exactly needs proving here?

Comment: @whuber I meant that I cannot provide the rules, from which it follows, exactly.

Comment: Scalar multiplication of matrices is commutative.